# Bubble Sort on singly linked list Worst Time Complexity?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

I know that a singly linked list only points to the next value and cannot point to the previous value, so am I right to think that in a bubble sort the list would act the same as an array where it only goes in one direction? If that was the case would the time complexity be O(n^2)?

Comment: Yes, a bubble sort in a list has the same time complexity as a bubble sort in an array. And that time complexity is quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream> 

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;


struct Node* swap(struct Node* ptr1, struct Node* ptr2)
{
    struct Node* tmp = ptr2->next;
    ptr2->next = ptr1;
    ptr1->next = tmp;
    return ptr2;
}


int bubbleSort(struct Node** head, int count)
{
    struct Node** h;
    int i, j, swapped;

    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {

        h = head;
        swapped = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++)
        {

            struct Node* p1 = *h;
            struct Node* p2 = p1->next;

            if (p1->data > p2->data)
            {


                *h = swap(p1, p2);
                swapped = 1;
            }

            h = &(*h)->next;
        }


        if (swapped == 0)
            break;
    }
}
/* Function to print the list */
void printList(struct Node* n)
{
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << n->data << " -> ";
        n = n->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void insertAtTheBegin(struct Node** start_ref, int data)
{
    struct Node* ptr1
        = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    ptr1->data = data;
    ptr1->next = *start_ref;
    *start_ref = ptr1;
}

//------------------------------------------- Driver Code 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 80,34,232,22,50,6 };
    int list_size, i;

    struct Node* start = NULL;
    list_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
        insertAtTheBegin(&start, arr[i]);

    std::cout << "Linked list before sorting\n";
    printList(start);

    bubbleSort(&start, list_size);

    std::cout << "Linked list after sorting\n";
    printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see indeed a bubble sort in a list has the same time complexity as a bubble sort in an array but the only difference is that the time complexity is quadratic.

Comment: Hi! I am quite confused of your explanation, is it not both scenarios have quadratic time complexities?

Comment: Both have same time complexities

Comment: @Monsi Think generally ,your swapping both in linked list and array the same way and the only difference is the way you access it. So obviously the time complexity will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be.

Although you should note that for singly linked list implementation, you will need to keep track of the previous pointer as well for the swap operation, to handle the next pointer links.

Comment: You don't need to keep track of the previous pointer, you use a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `node` as well as a *pointer-to* `node` to do that. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) and e.g., [C++ Template Singly-Linked List w/Sort](https://pastebin.com/Sq1MPU15)

Comment: In bubble sort you only swap neighboring node.